# Python file testing line in BASH program failing with syntax error

Tags: python, bash

Hey guys I'm trying to integrate some PY into my shell script and running across
the following error, I though quote should have quoted my variable but it looks
like it's not doing what I expected, can someone help me troubleshoot this?

```
#!/bin/bash
host='user@localhost' 
path='/home/user/file' 

python -c "return subprocess.call(['ssh', '$host', 'test -e ' + pipes.quote($path)]) == 0"

  File "<string>", line 1
    return subprocess.call(['ssh', "user@localhost", 'test -e ' + pipes.quote(/home/jdaniel/sent)]) == 0
                                                                                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
python -c "return subprocess.call(['ssh', '$host', 'test -e ' + pipes.quote(\"$path\")]) == 0"
```

I would assume

as an aside .. why are you not just calling ssh from the bash? what benefit are you getting by using python here in this fashion?  and do you not need to use `import subprocess` when you use the `-c` flag?

I would choose to do this whole program either in python or bash ... but mixing them like this feels slightly silly (especially given what your python code does)

Comment: File "<string>", line 1 SyntaxError: 'return' outside function ??

Comment: Just trying to learn some PY to compliment my bash, plus bash doesn't really have a sane way for testing if files exist on another server. I guess I could use rsync, but it doesn't sound as interesting I guess.

Comment: yeah since you cannot have a return outside a function ... which you have a return as the only line in the program ... but thats a different problem ... but just delete the word "return" from your python code ...  all your doing is calling the ssh program from inside python ... this is 100% the same as if you called it from bash afaik...

Comment: Working code was `python -c "import subprocess, pipes; print subprocess.call(['ssh', '$host', 'test -e ' + pipes.quote(\"$path\")]) == 0"` just a heads up =) waiting to accept your answer, and plus one. Thanks Joran

Comment: glad to hear :) ... I figured you would get it ... but I still dont understand why ... :P

Comment: @dodomeki - Neither does Python, or you wouldn't be shelling out to `ssh` to check.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to change this

```
pipes.quote($path)
```

to

```
pipes.quote('$path')
```

as pipes.quote() is expecting a string

I'd say Its better to use shell instead of python

```
#!/bin/bash
host='user@localhost' 
path='/home/user/file' 
ssh -q $host "test -e $path"
```

Comment: That's true, but I wasn't trying to do it in BASH, thank you though